Fundamental group of the homeomorphism group of a compact manifold
Let $X$ be a compact connected manifold and $\mathcal H(X)$ be the group of all homeomorphisms of $X$, equipped with the compact-open topology. Is the fundamental group of $\mathcal H(X)$ countable? Is it finitely generated?

Maybe it is locally contractible and every locally contractible Polish group has a countable fundamental group?

It is locally contractible - this result is due to A. V. Černavskij (1969).

Normally $\mathcal H(X)$ is disconnected, for example if $X$ is a surface than the connected components comprise the mapping class group. So normally you consider $\pi_1$ of the identity component (ofc since $\mathcal H$ is a group, all components have the same fund gp).

Sure, it is all about the identity component.

So, in the space of based loops, the (based) homotopy relation seems to be open, so that there are countably many equivalence classes.

@KevinCasto $\pi_1$ is defined for any based topological space, no need of connectedness. Of course this "ignores" all other path components.

@YCor Sure, but extremely often people speak of "the fundamental group of a space" (for example, in this question) because we are used to connected spaces where we can ignore basepoint issues.

@KevinCasto yes, and this is an abuse of language to ignore basepoints. But topological groups have a canonical basepoint, so things are clear-cut.

By Lemma 8.6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.01755 it is countable. It need not be finitely-generated, e.g. by Example 3 of https://msp.org/pjm/1976/67-2/p09.xhtml.

It turned out that what YCor suggested in his first comment is true. Every connected separable locally contractible topological group has a countable fundamental group. The proof goes by looking at the universal cover, first noticing that it is separable, being generated by a separable identity neighbourhood, and then recalling that the fundamental group of the original group is in bijective correspondence with the fibres. These are countable by separability of the universal cover.

Let $X$ be a compact topological manifold. Since $\mathcal{H}(X)$ is a separable metric space and $S^n$ is compact, the mapping space $C(S^n,\mathcal{H}(X))$ in the compact-open topology is also a separable metric space.
Since $\mathcal{H}(X)$ is locally contractible topological group [Cer], it is locally equiconnected [Fox]. Since $S^n$ is compact Hausdorff, the space $C(S^n,\mathcal{H}(X))$ is also locally equiconnected [Mil, Le.3].
Now consider the evaluation fibration sequence
$$
C_*(S^n,\mathcal{H}(X))\rightarrow C(S^n,\mathcal{H}(X))\xrightarrow{ev}\mathcal{H}(X).
$$

Theorem (Heath [Hea]) If $p:E\rightarrow B$ is a Hurewicz fibration and $E,B$ are locally equiconnected metric spaces, then for any $x\in B$, the fibre $p^{-1}(x)$ is locally equiconnected. $\quad\blacksquare$

It follows that $C_*(S^n,\mathcal{H}(X))$ is locally equiconnected and hence locally contractible. Thus $C_*(S^n,\mathcal{H}(X))$ has open path components. Since it is a separable metric space, it has at most countably many path components. Thus we have:

Proposition If $X$ is a compact manifold, then for any $n\geq$ the group $\pi_n(\mathcal{H}(X))\cong\pi_0(C_*(S^n,\mathcal{H}(X)))$ is countable. $\quad\blacksquare$

The ingredients of the proof were that $\mathcal{H}(X)$ is separable metric and locally contractible. The first condition holds for any second-countable manifold (which is hemicompact), and Černavskii has results taking care of the second condition.

Proposition The statement of the previous proposition holds when $X$ is an open manifold which is the interior of a compact manifold. $\quad\blacksquare$

References
[Cer] A. Černavskii, Local contractibility of the group of homeomorphisms of a manifold, (Russian) Mat. Sb. (N.S.) 79 (121) (1969), 307-356.
[Fox] R. Fox, On fibre spaces. II, Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society. 49 (1943), 733–735.
[Hea] P. Heath, A Pullback Theorem for Locally-Equiconnected Spaces, Man. Math 55 (1986), 233-238.
[Mil] J. Milnor, On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW complex, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 90 (1959), 272-280.
